# How to register my account for api.dev.twilio.com endpoint?

Tags: api, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have some question about api.dev.twilio.com endpoint. How to create  dev.twilio.com account and what is the useful of dev account.
Also what is the difference between normal account and dev.twilio.com account

Normal endpoint is api.twilio.com
Dev endpoint is api.dev.twilio.com

Can I use my normal account for api.dev.twilio.com endpoint?

What is needed for Twilio dev account and how can I get this account

Answer (score 1):

dev.twilio.com and *.dev.twilio.com are not public endpoints so having an account there is not going to be an option.

With that said, if you were interested in running tests against your application that uses Twilio you can use the [test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials) for your account.

If you are looking at a dev versus prod environment you might consider opening a second account or a subaccount. Again, both at the twilio.com level.